# Headlight troubleshooting, where do I start?

Tags: headlight, f-250

I have a 1991 F250.  I was driving the other day and my foot bumped the switch for high beam/ low beam on the floor board, next to the parking brake and clutch pedal.  I noticed, as my headlamp was turned on, the lights would turn off while my parking lights stayed on as well as my dash lights.  So I tried bumping the switch with my foot but this time on purpose and the headlamps went right back on.  The next evening the same had happened but this time the headlamps would not turn back on.  How would I go about troubleshooting my problem?  Where should I start?  I am assuming with my fuse first?  Then where to after is it's not my fuse?  Please help, my truck is useless when the sun goes down, like having curfew.

Comment: You can check the fuses, but I'll bet your floor switch is the issue.

Comment: The floor switch has some good reasons for first check. This what initiated the problem. They are accessible , cheap, easy to replace. The likelyhood of a 1991 having a body leak that puddles on the floor and rusts the switch is pretty high.